# Issues with Ubuntu 20.04 on HP ProBook 4530s

Tags: 20.04, intel-graphics, hp, amd-graphics

I'm fairly new to Linux and I wanted to get into it by installing Ubuntu 20.04 (single boot) on my old HP ProBook 4530s. I apparently installed it through USB successfully.
Nevertheless, I got some issues when booting it up for the 1st time by only getting this frozen message:

```
/dev/sda6: recovering journal
/dev/sda6: clean, xxx/xxx files, xxx/xxx blocks
```

(where x are some random numbers)

After looking around I managed to only successfully boot it up with "nomodeset" on the GRUB settings. But it seems to be a quick fix to allow the installation of the proper graphics drivers, since now it can't use more than a resolution of 1024x768 and the GPU performance might be affected. It seems that my pc has a hybrid graphics card system with AMD/Intel and I'm not sure how to properly update/install the right drivers. Also using "additional drivers" didn't work . Here's my graphics info:

```
~$ lshw -c video
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:d4a00000-d4a1ffff ioport:5000(size=256) memory:d4a20000-d4a3ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d4000000-d43fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Question: Am I right on that it seems to be a graphic drivers problem? If so, could you guide me a bit on how to install the right drivers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more looking around I've found a solution, might not be the best one but it's better than before, by changing the BIOS' settings switchable graphics to integrated graphics and then a fresh re-install of Ubuntu, just in case.

Now it boots correctly and graphics seem to be working properly, although it might only be using Intel's integrated graphics card, so it might not be performing at its maximum.

If someone else has had a similar problem and has managed to make both AMD Radeon HD 6470M and Intel integrated graphics card work, let me know!